# Fetching all planner Task through Graph API

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-graph, graph-api, office-graph

[image]

**Why i am getting null value in {"CreatedBy : User :DisplayName"} and also in  {"Assignments : AssignedBy :User :DisplayName"}**

Answer (score 1):

Per my test, I got the same result as yours. The property DisplayName shows null vaule for user:

[image]

I would suggest you sumbmit feeback for this bug：https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/support